# how to parse arbitrary json file in gwt?

Tags: json, gwt

I am writing a GWT application where I need to load and parse arbitrary JSON file.

So I think the overlay type is not very useful in this case since I do not know the schema/format of the file beforehand.

I've done some research online but still can't figure out a way of doing so.
Can someone please give some ideas on how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you don't know the *schema* in advance, you're ([unfortunately](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=2900)) left with the [`JSONParser`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/json/client/JSONParser.html).

Comment: Yes, unfortunately. Why not follow Crockford's design?

Answer (score -1):

You could first construct `JavaScriptObject` from string/file

```
private final native JavaScriptObject asJavaScriptObject(String json) /*-{
    eval('var res = ' + json);
    return res;
}-*/;
```

and then use it to create [`JSONObject`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/json/client/JSONObject.html) which has methods for accessing JSON properties and checking if they exist.

```
new JSONObject(asJavaScriptObject(json));
```

Comment: There's [`JsonUtils`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/JsonUtils.html) for parsing to a `JavaScriptObject`.